# setImageResource() with attrs value

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-attributes

I'm trying to put an image to my `ImageView`, with a custom attribute defined by me, I'm doing it this way:

**Attrs:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyAttr">
        <attr name="my_image" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**ImageView Attrs:**

```
app:my_image="@drawable/image"
```

Than in my `View`:

```
int imageSrc;
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyAttr, 0, 0);
try {
    imageSrc = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyAttr_my_image, -1);
} finally {
    ta.recycle();
}
```

And set the image to the `ImageView` with:

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageSrc);
```

But nothing appears, I've tried also with:

```
imageSrcDrawable = ta.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyAttr_my_image);
```

And:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageSrcDrawable);
} else {
    imageView.setBackground(imageSrcDrawable);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've already tried to parse attribute with `ta.getInt(..)` and its work fine!

I can not understand why, thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you just use `android:src="@drawable/image"`?

Comment: Because I need custom attrs for LinearLayout custom class @petey

Comment: that doesnt really explain why you aren't using the [ImageView xml attr of `android:src`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) and it appears you might be trying to re-invent a wheel android already gave you. If this is not the case,  please post your custom LinearLayout class.

Comment: It can be but let's say that I want to do such a thing as I do ?

Comment: Fair enough,  please post the full code of your "custom" View

Comment: I do not think much use.
The problem is linked to that, trust me there is nothing that can affect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been useful if you had included the Layout XML code, however, I'm going to take a stab in the dark and suggest you might have a problem with the name-spacing. Have you defined the namespace in your Layout XML as

```
xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourcompany.yourpackage"
```

If not, I'd give that a spin. Other suggestions:

I believe that `obtainStyledAttributes` actually resolves all the attributes when you call it on the AttributeSet. So, I wouldn't be surprised if the TypedArray instance already contains the resolved resource id, in short: try and use

```
imageSrc = ta.getInt(R.styleable.MyAttr_my_image, -1);
```

as opposed to `ta.getResourceId()`. And finally, if all the above fails, I would try and use `ta.hasValue(R.styleable.MyAttr_my_image)` do determine if the value actually exist, if not, then atleast you know that `obtainStyledAttributes` didn't successfully parse and resolve the attribute, and thus, you can start looking into why. As in, file locations, namespaces etc.

Hope you get it working.

**EDIT:**

After reading your comments, I only got one last question, from the snippets above, I can't see which method you are actually initialising this in, and I'm wondering if your image view is being redrawn afterwards. I'm presuming that `imageView.setImageResource(imageSrc);` invalidates the imageView, however, since its now showing up, and you just confirmed that your 100% sure that it loaded correctly, then it might we worth invalidating it manually, just to check, that is trying a `imageView.invalidate();` after calling `image.setImageResource()`.

Comment: I've java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/image.png" on ta.getInt(...)

Comment: Ok, cool. Was just a thought, at-least now you know that the obtainStyledAttributes is doing its job ;-)

Comment: I knew this already , that's why I could not understand exactly what it could be!!!

Comment: we'll it would have been useful if you would have included that information ;-) that you had determined that it was parsed, normally when somebody tried different ways of retrieving data, and setting data. It suggests that he/she isn't sure whats going on. Anyways, are you sure its being redrawn after you set the src? (i'll update my question)

Comment: tried with invalidate() and postInvalidate() but nothing, if i load with setImageResource(R.drawable.image) it works..

Comment: Oh..it works! I noticed a little thing in the code that could be detrimental and ineffetti was so ! Thanks again his response was useful to understand the possible dynamics of the incident!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here

```
private int getResourceFromAttr(int attr)
{
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = getActivity().getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(attr, typedValue, true);
    int res_ = typedValue.resourceId;
    return res_;
}
```

Then set the Image

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.main_logo);
    int res = getResourceFromAttr(R.attr.img_main_logo);
    imageView.setImageResource(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help who may be looking for something simple

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ItemView">
        <attr name="icon" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

```java
    private fun setLayout(attrs: AttributeSet?) {
            attrs?.let { attributeSet ->
                val attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attributeSet,
                    R.styleable.ItemView
                )
    
                val icon = attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.ItemView_icon)
    
                binding.itemIcon.setImageDrawable(icon)
    
                attributes.recycle()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).